# No muestra los markers en el google maps utlizando Html2Canvas - VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue2-google-map

He realizado un capturador de pantalla con la librería Html2Canvas en Google maps y estoy teniendo un problema de compatibilidad con el transform de css3 que utiliza google. El mapa si me lo muestra, pero con un espacio en el lateral y los markers no me los muestra.

Así se debería de mostrar la captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así se muestra cuando realizas la captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He visto que una posible solución es añadir en el código las siguientes líneas:

```
left:0,
top:0,
"transform":transform
```

Pero no me funciona ya que los he probado metiendolos en línea desde el navegador. Os adjunto mi código

Component.Vue

```
async print() {
      const el = this.$refs.captureMap
      // add option type to get the image version
      // if not provided the promise will return
      // the canvas.
      const options = {
        type: 'dataURL',
        useCORS: true
      }
      this.output = await this.$html2canvas(el, options)
        // console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('gm-style'))
        // document.getElementsByClassName('gm-style').style.left="0px"
        // document.getElementsByClassName('gm-style').style.top="0px"
        // document.getElementsByClassName('gm-style').style.transform="none"
    }
```

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.